# Is it possible to extract full accurate image tag from a html code using DOM in php?

Tags: php, html, dom

I'm trying to get full accurate img tags from a html code using DOM:

```
$content=new DOMDocument();
$content->loadHTML($htmlcontent);
$imgTags=$content->getElementsByTagName('img');
foreach($imgTags as $tag) {
echo $content->saveXML($tag); }
```

If i had the original `<img   src="img">`, the result would be `<img src="img"/>`. But i need the exact value corresponding to the original.

It is possible - to get the exact img tag using DOM without regular expressions or thirdparty libraries (Simple HTML DOM)?

Comment: so you want to find `<img />` elements that have extra spaces in?

Comment: `DOMDocument` converts the text you load into a tree-structure representation of the document. White-space is normalised in HTML. So, in a nutshell, no it isn't possible to use it to get the exact original text of your `<img />` element including the extra spaces in this way. What actual problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @AlexThomas i want to find exact `img` elements using DOM, they may have extra spaces or `/` may be missing. To then cut this substring from the original string, if certain conditions are met in the cycle.

Comment: As I said, this isn't possible. However, you **could** remove the images from the `DOMDocument` if the conditions are met, and then save the document to get the HTML with the images removed.

Comment: @Matt Raines I need to add a condition in this `foreach` cycle in which is possible to remove the `$tag` from the original `$htmlcontent`.

Comment: @MattRaines Ok, thanks, i understand. I try to use something like `$tag->parentNode->removeChild($tag);`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. It isn't possible to do this.

However, you can achieve your goal of removing the `<img>` elements from an HTML document if they meet specific conditions using `DOMDocument`. Here's some sample code which removes images which contain the `class` attribute "removeme".

```
$htmlcontent =
    '<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title>Example</title></head><body>'
    . '<img src="1"><img src="2" class="removeme"><img src="3"><img class="removeme" src="4">'
    . '</body></html>';

$content=new DOMDocument();
$content->loadHTML($htmlcontent);

foreach ($content->getElementsByTagName('img') as $image) {
    if ($image->getAttribute("class") == "removeme") {
        $image->parentNode->removeChild($image);
    }
}
echo $content->saveHTML();
```

Output:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> <html><head><title>Example</title></head><body><img src="1"><img src="3"></body></html>
```

Comment: Now i tested this method. Unfortunately, it does not suit me - it adds the basic tags (`<!DOCTYPE>`,`<html>`,`<body>`) in the result and change the encoding. I work with the сyrillic, UTF-8, but after `saveHTML` everything breaks down.
Is it possible to delete <img> tags with DOM, withoout adding basic HTML tags to result?

Comment: In `$htmlcontent` variable i have a HTML code, not full HTML document. It is `post_content` of Wordpress's `wp_posts`. Does this have to use a third-party library? (do not want to use a regular expressions) Or is there some easier way?

Comment: It is certainly possible to remove these elements from `DOMDocument`. But you didn't ask this question. It's difficult to guess at what you want if you aren't specific. I'll edit the answer later but you could Google `LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED` and `LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD` for starters.

Comment: Thanks, i edited your answer with encoding addition.